# Leaflet infobox plugin

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web, plugins

I am searching a plugin for Leaflet, to have an infobox at the border of the map. Please look at my screenshot.

A click on the info button should be open a window. In this window I would like to have some additional informations.

I have not found such a plugin within https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html
Maybe I have overlook a plugin with this function?

[image]

Background software: I am use the gis qgis with qgis2web plugin. With this plugin  I can export a fully leaflet website. After export I have the possibilty to change the code and maybe insert a leaflet plugin.

Comment: From your question it's not clear how this info window should be displayed.  Outside the map? If outside the map, is this empty vertical strip present all the time or it should appear only when displaying info window?

Comment: Ohh. Maybe my picture with two screenshots are deceptive. The open infobox should be within the map, not outside. A user of the map should be have always the possibilty to get infos, for example infos about handling of the map. 
Unfortunately my english is not very precise.....I hope you understand what I want.
Click to button: open the window - 
click on "x": close the window

Comment: Not really the same style as your screenshot but a great plugin is the leaflet-sidebar : https://github.com/nickpeihl/leaflet-sidebar-v2

Comment: Another candidate would be Leaflet.SlideMenu (https://github.com/unbam/Leaflet.SlideMenu), see demo: http://unbam.github.io/Leaflet.SlideMenu/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and links. It should be help me.

Answer (score 3):

Control `L.control.info` below was written as an exercise of what does it take to write simple custom control as extension of basic `L.Control` object. It's not very 'by the book' and not very well tested, just an exercise.

Control  consists of button with (styled) title and (styled) text which is displayed uppon clicking on button.

Options:

- `title` - HTML formatted title text, default is `'Info'`
- `titleTooltip` - tooltip text for title button, default is `'Click here for more info'`
- `content` - HTML formatted text, which is displayed uppon button click
- `maxWidth` - maximum width of displayed content
- `titleClass` - CSS style class for title
- `contentClass` - CSS style class for content

Methods:

- `setTitle(txt)` - set title text
- `setTitleTooltip(txt)` - set title tooltip
- `setContent(txt)` - set content text
- `setTitleClass(cssClass)` - set CSS class for title
- `setContentClass(cssClass)` - set CSS class for content

Control:

```js
L.Control.Info = L.Control.extend({     

  options: {
    title: 'Info',
    titleTooltip: 'Click here for more info',
    content: '',
    maxWidth: '250px',
    titleClass: '',
    contentClass: ''
  },

  initialize: function(options) {        
    L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
    this._infoContainer = null;
    this._infoTitleContainer = null;
    this._infoBodyContainer = null;
    this._infoCloseButtonContainer = null;
    this._infoContentContainer = null;
    this._infoTitle = this.options.title;
    this._infoTitleTooltip = this.options.titleTooltip;
    this._infoContent = this.options.content;
    this._titleShown = false;
    this._titleClass = this.options.titleClass;
    this._contentClass = this.options.contentClass;
    this._infoTitleStyle = 'padding: 5px;';
    this._infoContainerClasses = 'leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control';
  },

  onAdd: function(map) {
    var infoContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-layers');

    var infoTitle = L.DomUtil.create('div');
    infoContainer.appendChild(infoTitle);
    infoTitle.setAttribute('style', this._infoTitleStyle);

    var infoBody = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-popup-content-wraper');
    infoContainer.appendChild(infoBody);
    infoBody.setAttribute('style', 'max-width:' + this.options.maxWidth);

    var infoContent = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-popup-content');
    infoBody.appendChild(infoContent);

    var infoCloseButton = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'leaflet-popup-close-button');
    infoContainer.appendChild(infoCloseButton);
    infoCloseButton.innerHTML = 'x';
    infoCloseButton.setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer');

    this._infoContainer = infoContainer;
    this._infoTitleContainer = infoTitle;
    this._infoBodyContainer = infoBody;
    this._infoContentContainer = infoContent;
    this._infoCloseButtonContainer = infoCloseButton;

    infoTitle.innerHTML = this._infoTitle;
    infoContent.innerHTML = this._infoContent;
    this._showTitle();

    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(infoContainer);
    L.DomEvent.on(infoCloseButton, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop);
    L.DomEvent.on(infoContainer, 'click', this._showContent, this);
    L.DomEvent.on(infoCloseButton, 'click', this._showTitle, this);

    return infoContainer;
  },

  onRemove: function(map){},

  setTitle: function(title) {
    this._infoTitle = title;
    if (this._infoTitleContainer != null) {
      this._infoTitleContainer.innerHTML = title;
    }
  },

  setTitleTooltip: function(titleTooltip) {
    this._infoTitleTooltip = titleTooltip;
    if (this._titleShown) {
      this._showTitleTooltip(true);
    }
  },

  setContent: function(content) {
    this._infoContent = content;
    if (this._infoContentContainer != null) {
      this._infoContentContainer.innerHTML = content;
    }
  },

  setTitleClass: function(titleClass) {
    this._titleClass = titleClass;
    if (this._titleShown) {
      this._addInfoClass(this._titleClass);
    }
  },

  setContentClass: function(contentClass) {
    this._contentClass = contentClass;
    if (!this._titleShown) {
      this._addInfoClass(this._contentClass);
    }
  },

  _showTitle: function (evt) {
    this._addInfoClass(this._titleClass);
    this._displayElement(this._infoTitleContainer, true);
    this._displayElement(this._infoBodyContainer, false);
    this._displayElement(this._infoCloseButtonContainer, false);
    this._showTitleTooltip(true);
    this._setCursorToPointer(this._infoContainer, true);
    this._titleShown = true;
  },

  _showContent: function (evt) {
    this._addInfoClass(this._contentClass);
    this._displayElement(this._infoTitleContainer, false);
    this._displayElement(this._infoBodyContainer, true);
    this._displayElement(this._infoCloseButtonContainer, true);
    this._showTitleTooltip(false);
    this._setCursorToPointer(this._infoContainer, false);
    this._titleShown = false;
  },

  _showTitleTooltip: function (showIt) {
    this._infoContainer.setAttribute('Title', (showIt) ? this._infoTitleTooltip : '');
  },

  _displayElement: function (element, displayIt) {
    element.style.display = (displayIt) ? '' : 'none';
  },

  _setCursorToPointer: function (element, setIt) {
    element.style.cursor = (setIt) ? 'pointer' : '';
  },

  _addInfoClass: function (classToAdd) {
    L.DomUtil.setClass(this._infoContainer, this._infoContainerClasses + ' ' + classToAdd);
  }
});

L.control.info = function(opts) {
  return new L.Control.Info(opts);
}
```

JSFiddel example: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/rqu3nvLj/

Comment: how could I initialitzed collapse=false ?

Comment: Control has no such option, you would have to edit it to add `collapse` option. At the moment you can achieve this with calling `myInfoControl._showContent();` after control is added to the map.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Another question, is it possible to add the side scrollbar option? I am using this control with a very long text and I need to limit the height and incorporate the scrollbar

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: I would appreciate indications on how to implement it

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of focused questions, which among other things mean one question per question. If you have new question how to code something different than in the above answer, post it as a separate question.