# Scrollbar to Leaflet L.control.info

Tags: leaflet

Related to the control `L.control.info` presented in the answer to the question [Leaflet infobox plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337746/leaflet-infobox-plugin), I would like to add the possibility to activate the height scrollbar for the mentioned control.

The conditions would be to be able to limit the height of the infobox using css styles. If the amount of text exceeds the infobox height, then the scrollbar should appear. Another alternative, perhaps simpler, would be to have the scrollbar active by default.

How could I implement this property in order to user a long text inside the infobox?

Comment: Added the proposed conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code of the control or inspect control content in the browser, you'll see that `leaflet-popup-content` CSS class is used for styling the control content. All you have to do to enable scroll for control content is to set `max-height` and `overflow-y: auto` for `leaflet-popup-content` class.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

**CSS**

```css
.titleStyle {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
}
.contentStyle {
  background-color: #FFFFE8;
}
.leaflet-popup-content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```js
const title = 'Pellentesque tristique';
const tooltip = 'Pellentesque tristique';
const text = '<div style="margin-bottom: 6pt;"><b>Pellentesque tristique</b></div>Pellentesque tristique, purus eu vestibulum interdum, purus neque lobortis lorem, non porttitor erat magna vitae purus. Sed sit amet turpis in elit viverra facilisis. Morbi varius nulla eu turpis ornare mollis. Maecenas vehicula feugiat lectus, molestie cursus metus pellentesque a. Aliquam vitae sapien maximus, ultricies ipsum vel, condimentum massa. Donec in nibh eu elit luctus tempor. Vivamus vel diam est. Ut bibendum mattis odio in consectetur. Aliquam blandit non turpis quis porttitor. Curabitur pellentesque, diam quis molestie cursus, nisi quam laoreet massa, nec gravida velit metus et arcu.'
const titleClass = 'titleStyle';
const contentClass = 'contentStyle';

const myInfoControl = L.control.info({
  position: 'topright',
  title: title,
  titleTooltip: tooltip,
  content: text,
  titleClass: titleClass,
  contentClass: contentClass
});
```

That's how the result would look like then:

[image]